# Записать в одну строку, если ID одинаковы

Tags: php, opencart

Есть скрипт, который делаем выгрузку, но есть проблема, когда к примеру у товара один и тот же ID, но разные опции, он выгружает их отдельно. Вот пример:

```
[0]
GoodID=112
Price=152.0000
Count=1
[1]
GoodID=111
Price=152.0000
Count=1
[2]
GoodID=111
Price=152.0000
Count=1
```

Это я выбрал так (один и тот же товар):
- Телефон (Красный)
- Телефон (Синий)
- Телефон (Зеленый)

Нужно, чтобы эти три телефона были в одной выдаче. Может можно поставить на игнорирование типы опций: 'image', 'checkbox'.

```
        $result_for_base_a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_option WHERE order_id = '$id' AND type = 'select';");
        for($j = 0; $j<count($result_for_base_a->rows); $j++) {
            $product_option_value_id=$result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_value_id'];
            $product_option_id=$result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_id'];

            $result_for_base_c = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option WHERE product_option_id = '$product_option_id'");
            $product_id=$result_for_base_c->row['product_id'];
            $result_for_base_b = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option_value WHERE product_option_value_id = '$product_option_value_id' AND product_id='$product_id'");
            $points = $result_for_base_b->row['points'];

            $price = $result_for_base_b->row['price'];
            $counts = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['quantity'];


$str .= <<<EOD
\n[$j]
GoodID=$points
Price=$price
Count=$counts
EOD;
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно извлекать такие товары группируя результат при помощи GROUP BY, а различающиеся столбцы получать в виде строки через запятую, воспользовавшись функцией GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(product_option_value_id) AS ids
FROM
  oc_product_option_value
WHERE
  product_id='$product_id'
```

Полученный таким образом список можно использовать для формирования более сложных вложенных запросов, например, с использованием конструкции IN().